# How to extract an integer from a string using regex

Tags: regex

I have a string like "something1 PP: 222 something2"  and I want to pick up 222 from this string. In general it can be any integer which is preceded by PP: and whatever follows is separated by a space. What is the regex to extract this pattern? I am new to regex and I am struggling

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it simply asks for code instead of explaining a problem.

Answer (score 2):

This should work (assuming JavaScript syntax, but easy to port):

`/PP: (\d+)/`

Example:

```
var match = 'something1 PP: 222 something2'.match(/PP: (\d+)/);

if (match) {
    var num = match[1];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regex pattern like this:

```
/\s(\d+)\s/
```

Where `\s` is a whitespace, `(\d+)` is a capture group, capturing at least one digit, and then another whitespace to follow (as per your example). In this particular example it is important to specify a boundary around the capture group (in your case spaces), because you don't want to capture the digit at the end of that string, or any others that may pop up in the string.

---

Online regex testing tools are VERY useful when you are learning, have a look at [regex101.com](http://regex101.com/r/qO1vW6).

Comment: This fails to satisfy the "preceded by PP:" requirement. That is, it will get false positives in a string like "something1 XX: 33 something2".